# XSLT mapping with metadata and field tags with multiple repetitive elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to perform XSLT transformation for XML having multiple repetitive elements. I need to match the `@id` attribute under `Records/Metadata` and `Record/Field` to get the respective output. I need to display all the field names and their output.

I am new to XSLT and any asistance in XSLT will be really helpful. Below is the input XML and the desired output.

Input:

```
<Records count="40">
  <Metadata>
    <FieldDefinitions>
      <FieldDefinition alias="Finding_ID" name="Finding ID" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" id="2260" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Status" name="Status" guid="68ecb49e-4eb6-492b-986f-43bf4a2f0d1f" id="2269" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Last_Updated" name="Last Updated" guid="b90f8e15-58d6-4fd6-b1d8-e9b008629723" id="2276" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Date_Closed" name="Date Closed" guid="f54c94c8-314f-4328-831b-ded5179fa95b" id="11224" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Expected_Completion_Date" name="Expected Completion Date" guid="a5ecc11f-ab40-483d-aff5-2f0a8e56e8d9" id="14653" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Actual_Completion_Date" name="Actual Completion Date" guid="6fc586cf-5709-47a9-a84c-a6b83141ce1d" id="14654" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Action_Plan_Review_Status" name="Action Plan Review Status" guid="82cc6d74-5881-4b23-9efb-e2b081d83e3f" id="30799" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="IC_Description" name="Corrective Action Plan" guid="bfb7b09b-b728-4dbf-a016-3ee232948793" id="14655" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Action_Plan_Status" name="Action Plan Status" guid="49c3b62c-4828-41e0-bcbc-3dbcf37fc08d" id="27953" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Audit_Date" name="Review Date" guid="0d7ad11f-0d8c-4cc8-a51b-8ceeddafa9b1" id="27955" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Questionnaire_ID" name="Questionnaire ID" guid="a6e1f48e-08b7-45b8-b885-b9368f4cea2c" id="30178" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Question_Name" name="Question Name" guid="9136a544-cc8e-442d-89af-4bb9c64b4a2e" id="30179" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Action_Plan_Reviewer_1" name="Action Plan Reviewer" guid="d3ae8a48-c0c8-45c5-96f8-29d1d6f1a086" id="30789" />
      <FieldDefinition alias="Facility_Name" name="Facility Name" guid="8cfba154-fc68-467c-810e-a9c6c69aa8a2" id="129" />
    </FieldDefinitions>
  </Metadata>
  <LevelCounts>
    <LevelCount count="40" guid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" id="62" />
    <LevelCount count="40" guid="7eb2544d-95aa-4122-9ee5-4f458f9cb1bc" id="60" />
  </LevelCounts>
  <Record parentId="0" moduleId="167" levelGuid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" levelId="62" contentId="288373">
    <Record parentId="0" moduleId="69" levelGuid="7eb2544d-95aa-4122-9ee5-4f458f9cb1bc" levelId="60" contentId="240937">
      <Field guid="8cfba154-fc68-467c-810e-a9c6c69aa8a2" id="129" type="1">5000-AR</Field>
    </Record>
    <Field guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" id="2260" type="6">4035</Field>
    <Field guid="a6e1f48e-08b7-45b8-b885-b9368f4cea2c" id="30178" type="1">288237</Field>
    <Field guid="9136a544-cc8e-442d-89af-4bb9c64b4a2e" id="30179" type="1">chemistry</Field>
    <Field guid="82cc6d74-5881-4b23-9efb-e2b081d83e3f" id="30799" type="4" />
    <Field guid="68ecb49e-4eb6-492b-986f-43bf4a2f0d1f" id="2269" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="1660" displayName="Open">Open</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Field>
    <Field guid="49c3b62c-4828-41e0-bcbc-3dbcf37fc08d" id="27953" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="101940" displayName="Open">Open</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Field>
    <Field guid="bfb7b09b-b728-4dbf-a016-3ee232948793" id="14655" type="1" />
    <Field guid="a5ecc11f-ab40-483d-aff5-2f0a8e56e8d9" id="14653" type="3" />
    <Field guid="6fc586cf-5709-47a9-a84c-a6b83141ce1d" id="14654" type="3" />
    <Field guid="f54c94c8-314f-4328-831b-ded5179fa95b" id="11224" type="3" />
    <Field guid="b90f8e15-58d6-4fd6-b1d8-e9b008629723" id="2276" type="22" xmlConvertedValue="2014-11-02T08:50:03.707Z">11/2/2014 2:50:03 AM</Field>
    <Field guid="d3ae8a48-c0c8-45c5-96f8-29d1d6f1a086" id="30789" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="217" domain="xyz" lastName="abc" firstName="h">habc</User>
      </Users>
    </Field>
    <Field guid="0d7ad11f-0d8c-4cc8-a51b-8ceeddafa9b1" id="27955" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2014-05-12T00:00:00Z">5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Field>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

Output:

```
<Record>
  <Data>
    <Finding_id>4035</Finding_ID>
    <Questionnaire_ID>288237<Questionnaire_ID>
    <Question_Name>chemistry<Question_Name>
    <!-- and so on -->
  </Data>
</Record>
```

Comment: What should it do with fields like 2269 (Status) and 27953 (Action_Plan_Status)? What should the output for those be?

Comment: @JLRishe: I need to display all the fields and their values.To be clear, Please see the complete sample output required using XSLT.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record>
<Data>
<Finding_id>4035</Finding_ID>
<Status>Open</Status>
<Last_Updated>11/2/2014 2:50:03 AM</Last_Updated>
<Date_Closed />
<Expected_Completion_Date />
<Actual_Completion_Date />
<Action_Plan_Review_Status />
<IC_Description />
<Action_Plan_Status>Open</Action_Plan_Status>
<Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
<Questionnaire_ID>288237<Questionnaire_ID>
<Question_Name>chemistry<Question_Name>
<Action_Plan_Reviewer_1>habc</Action_Plan_Reviewer_1>
<Facility_Name>5000-AR</Facility_Name>
</Data>
</Record

Comment: @Vivek Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand the structure of your input. There is only one Record (although the count says 40), and it has another Record nested inside it. I am not sure how exactly you want to handle this. Here's something you could use as your starting point, though:

**XSLT 1.0**
***edited***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="fname" match="FieldDefinition" use="@guid" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record">
            <Record>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Field | Record/Field"/>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field">
    <xsl:element name="{key('fname', @guid)/@alias}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field[key('fname', @guid)/@alias='Action_Plan_Reviewer_1']">
    <Action_Plan_Reviewer_1>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Users/User/@lastName, ' ', Users/User/@firstName)"/>
    </Action_Plan_Reviewer_1>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Record>
      <Finding_ID>4035</Finding_ID>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Question_Name>chemistry</Question_Name>
      <Action_Plan_Review_Status/>
      <Status>Open</Status>
      <Action_Plan_Status>Open</Action_Plan_Status>
      <IC_Description/>
      <Expected_Completion_Date/>
      <Actual_Completion_Date/>
      <Date_Closed/>
      <Last_Updated>11/2/2014 2:50:03 AM</Last_Updated>
      <Action_Plan_Reviewer_1>abc h</Action_Plan_Reviewer_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
   </Record>
</root>
```

**Note**:
If the guid values are constant, you could simplify the pattern in:

```
<xsl:template match="Field[key('fname', @guid)/@alias='Action_Plan_Reviewer_1']">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="Field[@guid='d3ae8a48-c0c8-45c5-96f8-29d1d6f1a086']">
```

Comment: Many thanks for the xslt and it is working well. With regards to count, the input xml is huge and I have provided only one chunk to have better understanding. Please ignore the count. In addition, could you please help in displaying first name and last name attributes in <Action_Plan_Reviewer_1> tag rather than displaying text element under the below tag. below will be the input and output should be "michael hor".                                           <Users>
        <User id="217" domain="xyz" lastName="hor" firstName="michael">hmichael</User>
      </Users>

Comment: @Vivek I am not sure I understand your request. Do you want to hard-code the reviewer's details into the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes. I need to apply the logic of concatenation of first name and last name for the reviewer's details. Rest of the fields are all direct mapping.

Comment: @Vivek I am afraid you're not being clear. Do you want to pull the name from the User section in the source XML, or hard-code some arbitrary name?

Comment: I want to pull out the {@firstname} and {@last name} attributes under <users> tag.

Comment: @Vivek Then why are you using my name to illustrate? That's confusing. Anyway, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: The output looks perfect. There is one more tag corresponds to facility field id 129 that is missing in the transformation. The XPATH is Records/Record/Record/Field Could you please help in populating that value as well. below is the corresponding XML part.                           <Record parentId="0" moduleId="69" levelGuid="7eb2544d-95aa-4122-9ee5-4f458f9cb1bc" levelId="60" contentId="240937">
      <Field guid="8cfba154-fc68-467c-810e-a9c6c69aa8a2" id="129" type="1">5000-AR</Field>
    </Record>

Comment: You are genius. Thanks for your help. I will apply this similar kind of xsl stylesheet for other complex xmls having similar structure. Will come back to you if anything. Once again many thanks.