# XSLT Creating repetitive elements from Complex XML with Field and Metadata ids

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use XSLT to transform one complex XML and ended up with the below output. Here is the XSLT stylesheet used.

XSLT Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="fname" match="FieldDefinition" use="@guid" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record">
        <Record>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Field"/>
        </Record>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Field">
    <Question><xsl:value-of select="key('fname', @guid)/@name" /></Question>
        <Answer><xsl:value-of select="."/></Answer>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Field[key('fname', @guid)/@alias='Questionnaire_ID' or key('fname', @guid)/@alias='Survey_Name' or key('fname', @guid)/@alias='Target' or key('fname', @guid)/@alias='Country' or key('fname', @guid)/@alias='Audit_Date' or key('fname', @guid)/@alias='CIR_Duration' or key('fname', @guid)/@alias='Overall_Training_Time'  ]">
<xsl:element name="{key('fname', @guid)/@alias}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field[key('fname', @guid)/@alias='CIM_1']">
    <xsl:element name="{key('fname', @guid)/@alias}">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Users/User/@lastName, ' ', Users/User/@firstName)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Record>
  <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
  <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
  <Target>5000-AR</Target>
  <Country>AR</Country>
  <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
  <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
  <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
  <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
  <Question>CIT-AML-001</Question>
  <Answer>No</Answer>
  <Question>CIT-CA-001</Question>
  <Answer>No</Answer>
  <Question>CIT-CA-002</Question>
  <Answer>Yes</Answer>
  <Question>CIT-CA-003</Question>
  <Answer>No</Answer>
  <Question>CIT-CP-001</Question>
  <Answer>Yes</Answer>
  <Question>CIT-CP-002</Question>
  <Answer>Yes</Answer>
</Record>
</root>
```

But I require the output to be in below format like below. Could you help how the XSLT sylesheet to be designed for the below scenario.For Each repetitive elements a new record needs to be created and I have to apply this logic for all questions.

The rest of the XML tags Questionnaire_ID,Survey_Name,Target,Country,CIM_1,Audit_Date,CIR_Duration,Overall_Training_Time should be untouched.

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Record>
  <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
  <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
  <Target>5000-AR</Target>
  <Country>AR</Country>
  <CIM_1>seaswar</CIM_1>
  <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
  <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
<Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
  <Question_Name>CITCAP001</Question_Name>
  <Answer>No</Answer>
  </Record>
    <Record>
  <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
  <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
  <Target>5000-AR</Target>
  <Country>AR</Country>
  <CIM_1>seaswar</CIM_1>
  <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
  <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
  <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
  <Question_Name>CITAML001_1</Question_Name>
     <Answer>No</Answer>
</Record>
      <Record>
  <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
  <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
  <Target>5000-AR</Target>
  <Country>AR</Country>
  <CIM_1>seaswar</CIM_1>
  <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
  <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
<Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
  <Question_Name>CITCAP003</Question_Name>
     <Answer>Yes</Answer>
 </Record>
</root>
```

Input XML is shared for your reference. Kindly bear with this big XML as there are multiple questions in it and I have illustrated my requirements with less questions. Have removed few questions since it is a very big XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Records count="2">
  <Metadata>
  <FieldDefinitions>
     <FieldDefinition id="24399" guid="35dc55b3-45c6-41e3-919a-8ff2832acdd0" name="Questionnaire ID" alias="Questionnaire_ID"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24401" guid="a9d47185-0f62-40f8-b557-f8d78099fcf6" name="Facility" alias="Target"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24418" guid="150ab6a4-a71f-49cf-abd5-609a672e0672" name="CIR Date" alias="Audit_Date"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24474" guid="cfa4cdef-1488-4cde-860e-424e4809ce11" name="CIT-HS-007" alias="CITHS007"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24477" guid="e0e9cf1d-721d-4335-9e60-847e8ddbde26" name="CIT-HS-014" alias="CITHS014"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24479" guid="cfe2c2a9-1eb8-4b90-a318-92f18e8cc3d9" name="CIT-HS-017" alias="CITHS017"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35714" guid="3be23703-af55-4b28-939e-2ed14291554e" name="Labor and Employment Training" alias="Labor_Employment_Training"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35715" guid="465aff23-cbc8-447c-9798-d3534c825cff" name="Licenses and Permits Training" alias="Licenses_Permits_Training"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35716" guid="280cc119-bc0c-4eb9-982d-79dc4f0ff8ae" name="Privacy Training" alias="Privacy_Training"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35717" guid="19f368dd-6327-4b20-99ce-bdbeab9f2615" name="Product Safety Training" alias="Product_Safety_Training"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="40975" guid="1af16fd4-d58b-4dc0-9c94-c053ae5f7d70" name="Survey Name" alias="Survey_Name"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35708" guid="a8d88884-f8fb-4d6d-97d9-a873674140e2" name="Consumer Protection Training" alias="Consumer_Protection_Training"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35709" guid="42478aad-9be5-41e4-8afd-c3865c78c4ee" name="Environmental Training" alias="Environmental_Training"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35710" guid="14adca11-89d1-4230-a653-3d5601978c95" name="Food Safety Training" alias="Food_Safety_Training"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35711" guid="63813055-51c1-4d55-8b9b-cafbd79381d3" name="Global Ethics Training" alias="Global_Ethics_Training1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35712" guid="9575a0e1-afc0-42b3-87b0-746f4ffbe9b6" name="Health and Safety Training" alias="Health_Safety_Training"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35713" guid="53945130-2fdc-480a-a6c2-3e640a21157e" name="Health and Wellness Training" alias="Health_and_Wellness_Training"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="31640" guid="a367fdb6-9029-453f-ac39-384876bbb769" name="CIT-LP-003" alias="CITLP003"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="31701" guid="f3992d86-ee90-4617-8afb-27105ebca956" name="CIR Duration" alias="CIR_Duration"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="34339" guid="fcf67af6-4fbc-4cb0-9110-0c34eb6a946a" name="CIT-CP-003" alias="CITCP003_1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35621" guid="cd8dc877-1e78-4a46-8c87-3a65652a1b4b" name="Overall Training Time" alias="Overall_Training_Time"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35705" guid="eb95b879-a64d-4adb-9936-5bf0192d4a44" name="Anti-Money Laundering Training" alias="Copy_of_AntiMoney_Laundering_Train_2"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="35706" guid="caf88c37-da7b-4f14-8539-25eb4de4f085" name="Compliance Awareness Program Training" alias="Compliance_Awareness_Training1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="30489" guid="b6939473-65ad-448a-a6b7-7be0345bccd8" name="CIT-FS-006" alias="CITFS006"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="30490" guid="16c3206c-45bb-4bc6-89f4-81740aec38e8" name="CIT-FS-007" alias="CITFS007"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="30491" guid="2559fc06-566e-413a-9af1-4874111d5678" name="CIT-PS-001" alias="CITPS001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="30850" guid="e762bf4e-2c2e-4c55-a889-a567cc06cebc" name="CIM" alias="CIM_1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="31638" guid="c9aa5bbf-df96-494b-a326-fd92f659d3a5" name="CIT-LP-001" alias="CITLP001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="31639" guid="f9b7a0a6-8e27-4816-81b1-908e65f2b47c" name="CIT-LP-002" alias="CITLP002"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="29218" guid="20552aa0-622b-475a-a1ee-226049335733" name="CIT-HS-010" alias="CITHS010_1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="30484" guid="fcf31a4e-bd37-4371-b57f-c992b5785768" name="CIT-FS-001" alias="CITFS001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="30485" guid="08691ec1-5208-48fb-aa50-d8cb10b613d7" name="CIT-FS-002" alias="CITFS002"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="30486" guid="b31ba3a4-f5bc-4b04-8579-d41e6f02afa2" name="CIT-FS-003" alias="CITFS003"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="30487" guid="9bfd9a6d-394b-4c03-b484-5ff710cadb3e" name="CIT-FS-004" alias="CITFS004"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="30488" guid="42191407-4576-43a4-b5ee-fb233542cdcb" name="CIT-FS-005" alias="CITFS005"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25378" guid="9d82e476-3357-4e28-9b2d-f4253237d4df" name="CIT-HS-015" alias="CITHS014_1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25725" guid="9d93571d-6f3b-40af-9d08-3a8df51e226f" name="CIT-AML-001" alias="CITAML001_1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25740" guid="a1c74b61-72dc-46aa-89d9-bc25fb68481f" name="Country" alias="Country"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25833" guid="0a549a54-7af7-4e73-b29b-670e83f7e434" name="CIT-PR-002" alias="CITPR002_1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="28711" guid="75240d0c-9126-474b-a44a-000568430ac9" name="CIT-MISC-001" alias="CITMISC001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="28712" guid="736551dd-8013-4c74-870a-da1ca5983e62" name="CIT-MISC-002" alias="CITMISC002"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25197" guid="22084156-3858-4ce4-b3c0-26cc263d9f0d" name="CIT-ENV-006" alias="CITENV006"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25198" guid="23345c53-9880-4f00-a9bd-46154d18374c" name="CIT-HW-004" alias="CITHW004"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25199" guid="fc3c51f3-e77e-4be0-ac3a-70296a8ad270" name="CIT-HS-013" alias="CITHS013"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25200" guid="28d2eae6-2c71-4e91-b02f-1af962b04e0b" name="CIT-HS-016" alias="CITHS016"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25207" guid="64622e90-615c-47c4-8e1a-3612fe23b494" name="CIT-HS-002" alias="CITHS002_1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25377" guid="f949fa2a-0fe2-4a4c-815d-3f71631e1506" name="CIT-HS-012" alias="CITHS011_1"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25181" guid="f1f33cd0-b2ce-4141-8842-0439ca61399e" name="CIT-HW-015" alias="CITHW015"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25182" guid="f9b6e558-b10b-4da5-83aa-b165934d2710" name="CIT-HW-016" alias="CITHW016"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25183" guid="d802a9f8-0a51-4451-be28-25f53c881912" name="CIT-HW-017" alias="CITHW017"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25184" guid="d3fad893-e8b0-44f8-b770-f1ee8f2ba9d3" name="CIT-CA-001" alias="CITCAP001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25185" guid="8a7dc8d8-0ed1-41db-8d48-666d8e846d82" name="CIT-CA-002" alias="CITCAP003"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25186" guid="820c6818-104e-4e4a-9551-fa4b1e2316de" name="CIT-CA-003" alias="CITCAP004"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24518" guid="feb8d30d-eda4-493a-ac24-88c5418f5037" name="CIT-EMP-002" alias="CITEMP002"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24519" guid="e70a4b05-958d-4c6b-a69f-63f7de775631" name="CIT-EMP-003" alias="CITEMP003"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24520" guid="72ae2b2c-b72a-4032-9460-6b6238eae84a" name="CIT-EMP-004" alias="CITEMP004"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24521" guid="ec732005-17b5-46a8-9cce-dc3b6ce34c9f" name="CIT-HS-001" alias="CITHS001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25179" guid="9c4ac981-b926-4fe2-9e26-86a9c6fc7069" name="CIT-HW-013" alias="CITHW013"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="25180" guid="fcd58ef4-5a53-4d3e-be4f-6b771497b14c" name="CIT-HW-014" alias="CITHW014"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24507" guid="187785d2-6fa9-4cad-8d34-056ea8e05a53" name="CIT-ENV-001" alias="CITENV001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24508" guid="28b6dbf8-6e2d-48dd-9f69-52cfd954bd7e" name="CIT-ENV-002" alias="CITENV002"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24509" guid="724cce4a-9266-4f4e-ac5f-86d673a621f7" name="CIT-ENV-004" alias="CITENV004"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24510" guid="d112520b-9ea7-40f1-b297-d5b47aa1fed9" name="CIT-ENV-005" alias="CITENV005"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24513" guid="2fcdb490-0f63-40a8-bf09-b48acb3ab5ee" name="CIT-CP-001" alias="CITCP001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24515" guid="6ec534aa-04e7-4d3f-9c3f-06c2303444d6" name="CIT-ETH-001" alias="CITETH001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24498" guid="6610bdd8-4288-462b-8b18-c48ade332653" name="CIT-HS-006" alias="CITHS006"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24499" guid="41a5487c-9fed-450b-9aa7-0010ea507aa2" name="CIT-HS-008" alias="CITHS009"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24500" guid="e79b4fdb-13c6-44b0-b45d-78006950fe8e" name="CIT-HS-009" alias="CITHS010"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24501" guid="c744f944-6bfe-42cc-8dd4-9f98b67bacd6" name="CIT-HS-011" alias="CITHS011"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24504" guid="3f2a847a-017f-43a7-9a2c-4dd17c209257" name="CIT-PR-001" alias="CITPR001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24506" guid="37151e1e-d41b-4ec1-b55d-e2a748ab5969" name="CIT-PR-003" alias="CITPR003"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24492" guid="82cf05e3-a532-4f61-bc8e-d84e44611cd1" name="CIT-CP-002" alias="CITCP002"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24493" guid="2b97d382-e5a5-482b-ba15-1ccc2af82353" name="CIT-ETH-002" alias="CITETH002"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24494" guid="8cd3b681-5158-49ab-93ba-8221c6a9df1c" name="CIT-EMP-001" alias="CITHS002"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24495" guid="7303f222-a629-4a77-8c22-07bb99c50c7c" name="CIT-HS-003" alias="CITHS003"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24496" guid="b54d1636-8745-425d-8e89-25fdcd0d36da" name="CIT-HS-004" alias="CITHS004"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24497" guid="aed45ae6-272f-4f65-86dc-432288719fb3" name="CIT-HS-005" alias="CITHS005"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24486" guid="022798d4-f7df-4c4a-8a00-c8b27ebac543" name="CIT-HW-007" alias="CITHW007"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24487" guid="00493fbe-26ac-4ebc-966f-b42f44a2eb97" name="CIT-HW-008" alias="CITHW008"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24488" guid="64b9528c-24dd-430b-9149-8deb3908545a" name="CIT-HW-009" alias="CITHW009"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24489" guid="fade3308-0d7e-4e89-b4f4-843fb0848bd9" name="CIT-HW-010" alias="CITHW010"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24490" guid="2e28d2b5-b2f4-424b-9793-b9b2e6a876c4" name="CIT-HW-011" alias="CITHW011"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24491" guid="4742b0c8-7362-434f-a4b1-7fdeef753940" name="CIT-HW-012" alias="CITHW012"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24480" guid="b949a566-646c-4421-bd66-c6ccf7058346" name="CIT-ENV-003" alias="CITENV003"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24481" guid="fb3e0f6e-d054-4b22-87de-85b8a9048e4b" name="CIT-HW-001" alias="CITHW001"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24482" guid="00fa19c0-832d-4f4e-87f6-a08cb9e9736d" name="CIT-HW-002" alias="CITHW002"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24483" guid="c70d424c-8ca4-479c-822d-c1f319db5aff" name="CIT-HW-003" alias="CITHW003"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24484" guid="fa5ad594-b2b4-492b-8bdd-052b175d7bef" name="CIT-HW-005" alias="CITHW005"/>
     <FieldDefinition id="24485" guid="be77515d-a140-47c9-8a5e-47b7576c082c" name="CIT-HW-006" alias="CITHW006"/>
  </FieldDefinitions>
 </Metadata>
 <LevelCounts>
  <LevelCount id="354" guid="513bd7fe-7a0d-47a3-b286-4f32c4219170" count="2"/>
 </LevelCounts>
 <Record contentId="288237" levelId="354" levelGuid="513bd7fe-7a0d-47a3-b286-4f32c4219170" moduleId="547" parentId="0">
  <Field id="24399" guid="35dc55b3-45c6-41e3-919a-8ff2832acdd0" type="6">288237</Field>
  <Field id="40975" guid="1af16fd4-d58b-4dc0-9c94-c053ae5f7d70" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="132670" displayName="Review">Review</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24401" guid="a9d47185-0f62-40f8-b557-f8d78099fcf6" type="9">
     <Reference id="240937">5000-AR</Reference>
  </Field>
  <Field id="25740" guid="a1c74b61-72dc-46aa-89d9-bc25fb68481f" type="1">AR</Field>
  <Field id="30850" guid="e762bf4e-2c2e-4c55-a889-a567cc06cebc" type="8">
     <Users>
        <User id="217" firstName="Sreevidhya" lastName="Easwaran" domain="HomeOffice">seaswar</User>
     </Users>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24418" guid="150ab6a4-a71f-49cf-abd5-609a672e0672" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2014-05-12T00:00:00Z">5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Field>
  <Field id="31701" guid="f3992d86-ee90-4617-8afb-27105ebca956" type="2">1</Field>
  <Field id="35621" guid="cd8dc877-1e78-4a46-8c87-3a65652a1b4b" type="2">9.96</Field>
  <Field id="25725" guid="9d93571d-6f3b-40af-9d08-3a8df51e226f" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="96791" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="25184" guid="d3fad893-e8b0-44f8-b770-f1ee8f2ba9d3" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="96192" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="25185" guid="8a7dc8d8-0ed1-41db-8d48-666d8e846d82" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="96193" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="25186" guid="820c6818-104e-4e4a-9551-fa4b1e2316de" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="96196" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24513" guid="2fcdb490-0f63-40a8-bf09-b48acb3ab5ee" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95324" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24492" guid="82cf05e3-a532-4f61-bc8e-d84e44611cd1" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95316" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24494" guid="8cd3b681-5158-49ab-93ba-8221c6a9df1c" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24518" guid="feb8d30d-eda4-493a-ac24-88c5418f5037" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24519" guid="e70a4b05-958d-4c6b-a69f-63f7de775631" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95324" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24520" guid="72ae2b2c-b72a-4032-9460-6b6238eae84a" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24507" guid="187785d2-6fa9-4cad-8d34-056ea8e05a53" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24508" guid="28b6dbf8-6e2d-48dd-9f69-52cfd954bd7e" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24480" guid="b949a566-646c-4421-bd66-c6ccf7058346" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95280" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24509" guid="724cce4a-9266-4f4e-ac5f-86d673a621f7" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24510" guid="d112520b-9ea7-40f1-b297-d5b47aa1fed9" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="25197" guid="22084156-3858-4ce4-b3c0-26cc263d9f0d" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="96202" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="25207" guid="64622e90-615c-47c4-8e1a-3612fe23b494" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="96206" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24495" guid="7303f222-a629-4a77-8c22-07bb99c50c7c" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24496" guid="b54d1636-8745-425d-8e89-25fdcd0d36da" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24497" guid="aed45ae6-272f-4f65-86dc-432288719fb3" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24498" guid="6610bdd8-4288-462b-8b18-c48ade332653" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24474" guid="cfa4cdef-1488-4cde-860e-424e4809ce11" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95261" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24499" guid="41a5487c-9fed-450b-9aa7-0010ea507aa2" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95324" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24500" guid="e79b4fdb-13c6-44b0-b45d-78006950fe8e" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="29218" guid="20552aa0-622b-475a-a1ee-226049335733" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="104290" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="24501" guid="c744f944-6bfe-42cc-8dd4-9f98b67bacd6" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95324" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="25377" guid="f949fa2a-0fe2-4a4c-815d-3f71631e1506" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="95325" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
  <Field id="25199" guid="fc3c51f3-e77e-4be0-ac3a-70296a8ad270" type="4">
     <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="96185" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
     </ListValues>
  </Field>
 </Record>
</Records>
```

Comment: can you add your input xml also thanks

Comment: @Treemonkey added input xml as well.

Comment: You should already know how to solve this from the answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098956/xslt-mapping-with-metadata-and-field-tags-with-multiple-repetitive-elements Just add a template for each field that needs individual treatment.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have edited the question with the modified XSLT that I have tried. Desired output is slightly changed. But I am unable to create a new record tag for each repetition element. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if something like this could work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="fname" match="FieldDefinition" use="@guid" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/Field[starts-with(key('fname', @guid)/@alias,'CIT')]">
            <Record>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../Field[not(starts-with(key('fname', @guid)/@alias,'CIT'))]"/>
                <Question>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('fname', @guid)/@name" />
                </Question>
                <Answer>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Field[1]"/>
                </Answer>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field">
    <xsl:element name="{key('fname', @guid)/@alias}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field[key('fname', @guid)/@alias='CIM_1']">
    <xsl:element name="{key('fname', @guid)/@alias}">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Users/User/@lastName, ' ', Users/User/@firstName)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-AML-001</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-CA-001</Question>
      <Answer>Yes</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-CA-002</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-CA-003</Question>
      <Answer>Yes</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-CP-001</Question>
      <Answer>Yes</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-CP-002</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-EMP-001</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-EMP-002</Question>
      <Answer>Yes</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-EMP-003</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-EMP-004</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-ENV-001</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-ENV-002</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-ENV-003</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-ENV-004</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-ENV-005</Question>
      <Answer>Yes</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-ENV-006</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-002</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-003</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-004</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-005</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-006</Question>
      <Answer>Yes</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-007</Question>
      <Answer>Yes</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-008</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-009</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-010</Question>
      <Answer>Yes</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-011</Question>
      <Answer>No</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-012</Question>
      <Answer>Yes</Answer>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Questionnaire_ID>288237</Questionnaire_ID>
      <Survey_Name>Review</Survey_Name>
      <Target>5000-AR</Target>
      <Country>AR</Country>
      <CIM_1>Easwaran Sreevidhya</CIM_1>
      <Audit_Date>5/12/2014 12:00:00 AM</Audit_Date>
      <CIR_Duration>1</CIR_Duration>
      <Overall_Training_Time>9.96</Overall_Training_Time>
      <Question>CIT-HS-013</Question>
      <Answer/>
   </Record>
</root>
```

Comment: The above solution works well if the question always starts with "CIT". The actual document which I am currently working  has few questions that doesn't contains the word "CIT".

Could you please check if it is possible to amend the XSLT in such a way that unique record needs to be created for each repetitive Question and Answer tags no matter what the question test is.

Comment: @Vivek If you want to have a record for each question, then you need a reliable test to determine which Field is (or isn't) a question (or an answer).

Comment: I have used one more XSLT on top of the above XSLT  to get the output. Can this be merged into a single XSLT. PFB the 2nd XSLT used.



<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
<xsl:for-each select="root/Record/Question">
<Record>
<xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::Question orself::Answer)]"/>
<xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::Answer[1]"/>
</Record>
</xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Either edit your question, or (preferably, IMHO) post a new one.